# Weighted Average of elements in dictionary

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a dictionary like this:

```
let tempDict = [100:2, 101:3, 102:4]
```

I need to find the weighted average of all the elements in the dictionary. So I essentially want to do this

```
let keyMultValues = 100*2+101*3+102*4
let valTotal = 2+3+4
let final = keyMultValues/valTotal
```

I know I can loop through all the items in a dictionary but I thought maybe there is a more efficient and cleaner way to do this.

Is there a better way than this?

```
var keyMultValues = 0.0
tempDict.forEach({
    keyMultValues += $0.key*$0.value
})
let valTotal = reduce(priceDict.values, 0, +) //this part isn't working properly so any help you can give here would be great. I am using swift 4
```

Comment: `reduce(priceDict.values, 0, +)` is Swift 1 syntax. In Swift 2, a whole bunch of these disorganized free-functions were moved to be instance methods on Sequence et al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
let keyValueProductsSum = dict.lazy.map(*).reduce(0, +)
let valueSum = dict.values.reduce(0, +)
let weightedAverage = keyValueProductsSum / valueSum
```

Comment: let me take a look. just out of curiosity, what is the lazy for? what does it do?

Comment: @NevinJethmalani It defers the production of an Array to contain the results of `map`. Since we're only going to iterate the values and sum them with `.reduce(0, +)`, there's no reason to have `map` waste time in allocating a new `Array`, and copying all the results into it, only for us to discard the array after iterating it once.

Comment: so if we took the lazy out would it still work the same way but just be a worse way of doing it?

Comment: You can simplify your map passing just the operator `map(*)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh true!

Comment: @NevinJethmalani Yep, try it for yourself. Profile it with a really large array, and you'll see the difference

Answer (score 2):

Two observations:

1. If you're doing weighted average, you probably don't want to do integer calculation. You probably want floating point result.
2. You may want to avoid overflow issues stemming from multiplying all the keys by the values and then adding them up and then dividing by the sum of the values. You might want to do that value by value:

Thus:

```
let sumOfWeights = dictionary.reduce(0.0) { $0 + Double($1.value) }
let weightedAverage = dictionary.reduce(0.0) { $0 + Double($1.key) * Double($1.value) / sumOfWeights }
```

Note, this works with the original values:

```
let dictionary = [100:2, 101:3, 102:4]
```

This also works with large values, too, e.g.:

```
let dictionary = [
    1_000_000_000: 20_000_000_000,
    1_000_000_001: 30_000_000_000,
    1_000_000_002: 40_000_000_000
]
```

Comment: awesome! thanks! We only have a couple of values in the dictionary so we won't need to worry about those issues. But I will look into this!

Answer (score 0):

You started with:

```
var keyMultValues = 0
tempDict.forEach({
   keyMultValues += $0.key*$0.value
})
let valTotal = reduce(priceDict.values, 0, +) //this part isn't working properly so any help you can give here would be great. I am using swift 4
```

and ask:

> Is there a better way than this?

Well your error is you've written the `reduce` incorrectly, it should have been:

```
tempDict.values.reduce(0, +)
```

and with this fix your code produces the correct (using integer arithmetic) result.

However your code does *two* passes over the data, the `foreach` and the `reduce` (and the other answers at the time of writing do two or *three*). Your own solution shows you only need to do one pass, just modify it to follow the same pattern for `valTotal` as you used for `keyMultValues`:

```
var keyMultValues = 0
var valTotal = 0
tempDict.forEach({
   let val = $0.value // we are going to use it twice
   keyMultValues += $0.key * val
   valTotal += val
})
let final = keyMultValues / valTotal
```

This uses just one pass over the data.

If your numbers are large you might need to do two passes using the "divide as you go algorithm", and if you wish to find the floating-point weighted average then you need to throw a few `Double` casts in. Both of those are covered by @Rob's answer.

Is one pass over the data really better (faster, less memory, whatever) than two? That is left as an exercise! I added this answer just to show you how close your original attempt was to a correct solution.